# different scss based on text direction

Tags: angular, sass

I am trying to apply different scss based on direction of text, like below:

```
.test {
  text-align: right;
}

[dir=rtl] .test  { text-align: left }
```

when the direction of html changes, the style of (rtl) doesn't apply to the class.

Is something wrong with the syntax?

thanks,

Comment: Does this help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:dir

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: Could you provide your html ? Where do you apply the *dir* attribute ?

Comment: sorry for the delay, I have closed this issue and solved temporarily with flex box. Appreciate your support